# Exporting Crystal Report to PDF throws error: Error detected by export DLL: (541)

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

We have several Crystal Reports (version 8.5) that we run from VB6 and VB.Net. Most of these work just fine to export to PDF, but two reports (out of many) throw this error when exporting to PDF:

Error detected by export DLL: (541)

The error seems to be an unhandled error in Crystal, and we've tried changing every parameter we can think of with no luck. Any ideas? TIA.

Comment: Need more info: stack trace, code examples (how are you exporting),... Does your report contain sub-reports, dynamically loaded images, unusual fonts, etc? Does this error occur in both VB6 and vb.net?

Comment: Our software is an add-in to in a much larger ERP system, so we automate the export of the report through that system's API. It's written in VB6, but they don't share their source code so I wouldn't be able to get a sample of how they are calling it. The error itself is thrown within Crystal (not the ERP system) and bubbles up. Since that is a pretty specific error number, my hope was that someone would at least be able to help us narrow it down, as the ERP publisher does not have many resources to throw at the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your exact problem, but since this only happens to 2 reports out of many, here's a few suggestions you may not have asked yourself yet:

1. Does this happen every time or sporadically? (If it's sporadic, consider network/server issues)
2. Are these 2 reports brand new or have they worked quite well for a long time and have just now crashed? If it's the latter, look at any new programs you've installed.
3. What's different about these 2 reports? Are the PDFs saved in a different location than the others?
4. Do they pull data from different sources than the other reports?
5. The most drastic solution would of course be to rewrite the rpt file from scratch.

### Edit

Some googling found this [page](http://p2p.wrox.com/pro-vb-net-2002-2003/6993-crystal-8-5-missing-out-date-export-dll.html). The links on this forum topic have been dead for years, but here's a possibility:

1. Copy the files from the following directory:
   %systemroot%\Crystal
2. Paste the files to the System directory.
   For example, in Terminal Server, the
   System directory is generally:
   Winnt\System32

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have an exact answer to this problem. However, it turns out that if you just catch the exception and ignore it, everything continues on and the PDF export is created just fine. Hope this can help someone else down the road...

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the ExportModeller.dll v 9.1.1.527. You must install the pach.

Like reported here (in italian) http://blogs.sysadmin.it/ermannog/archive/2009/04/28/3258.aspx
you have to download the patch for crystal report named crnet11win_en.zip(can find searching  on google), estract the file zipped in that file , and replace the file in your machine site on 
c:\%ProgramFiles%\file comuni\crystal decision\bin\1.0
and replace the file named ExportModeller.dll so that the version of the dll must be 9.1.1.528 and not 9.1.1.527.

If you look here can find the file crnet11win_en.zip already estracted 
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=174281e704ea1a69&id=174281E704EA1A69%21176